# Possible mixed-encoding string: how to find the missing character?

Tags: string, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters, unicode-literals

I have a PDF document that is mostly Farsi, but also includes some Latin characters with diacritics above or below from the [DMG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Morgenl%C3%A4ndische_Gesellschaft)'s [DIN 31635 standard for the transliteration of the Arabic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_31635). The PDF *mostly* displays both, the LTR- as well as the RTL-text, correctly and they can also *mostly* be extracted correctly by tools such as [TET](https://www.pdflib.com/products/tet/) (commercial) or GhostScript's `gs`.

Unfortunately, there are single characters, specifically in some (but not all) locations where there would have to be a `ḍ`¹ ([E1 B8 8D](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=E1+B8+8D&mode=bytes)) where a white rectangle containing `00 1F` ("information separator one") is instead rendered by Pango. I'm trying to use that one as an example for figuring out a way to correct all the other broken ones.

The other bytes of the word, before and after the one in question, are `20` (-), `77` (w) and `75` (u), then the `1F` itself, then `C5` (Å), `AB` («), `E2` (â), `80` (€) and `99` (™), then finally `20` (space) before the next word begins. The word itself, if it had been properly entered and were being properly displayed, would be `wuḍūʼ` (the DMG-representation of `وضوء`, meaning the ritual washing before prayer in Islam).

Gedit shows it like so:

[image]

Going through character by character, `75` and `77` are valid [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) as well as valid [Unicode Basic Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)). Then there is what certainly looks to be "latin small letter u with macron" (`01 6B`), but I see no `0`, `1`, or `6` in the hex representation. The same with the last character, which looks to be "right single quotation mark" (`20 1A`) if only there were a `1` or a `B` anywhere *after* `C5`. None of `1F C5` ([???](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=1F+C5&mode=bytes)), `AB E2` ([�](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=AB+E2&mode=bytes)) or `80 99` ([�](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=80+99&mode=bytes)) make any sense, either.

Two questions:

- Where am I failing in my understanding of how this string is composed?
- Based on the context, is there any way to find out what character encoding the "missing" character might originally (on the PDF's author's computer, perhaps) have been produced from?

—

¹ StackExchange seems to filter the funny character out; [uploaded a file containing only the word discussed](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sixtyfive/39ad90e2f46c9c4903c30b9ec1179538/raw/4806ab95ab8eb2faec12582c33060fde205f94c9/funnychar.txt).

Comment: From what you say, I would think there is a bug either in pango, or in the font, or in the file when it was encoded.

Comment: I don't care about the rendering, perhaps my phrasing can be misunderstood here. I just want to know what character(s) from what encoding(s) can be expressed by `1FC5ABE28099`, i.e.: between which bits of that sequence are the character boundaries and which character could have come from which encoding (and yes, I'm suspecting multiple encodings because of a problem when the file was saved, like you suggest).

Comment: `C5ABE2` is `ū` in UTF-8, `1F` is a control character (which pango display as `[00|1F]`), but `8099` is not valid UTF-8 (and Kanji in UTF-16). If you want to understand better, you should go a step earlier. What are the encoded values of `wu`? Maybe there are "escapes e.g. `1B`", as ISO2022. Could you check also how the arabic characters are encoded? UTF-8? ISO-2022? UTF-16? Such problems need a lot of detective work

Comment: It'll take a few days until I can look into it again. Thank you for your comment so far, Giacomo!